# I want to delete from text file based on some conditions using java

Tags: java

I am deleting specific data from text file. for that I am using below procedure
1) moving data from text file to String arraylist.
2) deleting specific data from arraylist.
3) moving data from arraylist to another file.

I want to delete data from text file for below condition. I am using checkboxes in my design page. 
1)If checkbox1 is not seleted then delete "A" from list.
2)If checkbox1 is not seleted then delete "B" from list.
3)If checkbox1 is not seleted then delete "C" from list.
4)If checkbox1 is not seleted then delete "D" from list.

I want to delete data from list based on above conditions and then remaining data need to store in new or existing file.

my file data is as follows

A -1 D -1 G -1 I -1 K -1 -2
A -1 D -1 G -1 J -1 K -1 -2
B -1 D -1 G -1 I -1 L -1 -2
C -1 E B -1 G -1 I -1 L -1 -2
C -1 F -1 H -1 I B -1 L -1 -2
C -1 F -1 H -1 J -1 K -1 -2
B -1 F -1 H -1 J -1 L -1 -2

For this purpose I have used below code-

```
ArrayList<String> collection = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> filter=new ArrayList<String> ();


    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")))
    {

        String sCurrentLine;

        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            collection.add(sCurrentLine);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
   if(!jCheckBox1.isSelected())
   { a=1;
   filter.add("A");
   } 
   if(!jCheckBox2.isSelected())
   { b=1;
   filter.add("B");}
   if(!jCheckBox3.isSelected())
   { c=1;
   filter.add("C");}
   if(!jCheckBox4.isSelected())
   { d=1;
   filter.add("D");}
   if(a==1)
   {
     collection.removeAll(filter);
      System.out.println("Done A");
   }
    if(b==1) 
    {
       collection.removeAll(filter);
       System.out.println("Done B");
    }
    if(c==1)
    {
       collection.removeAll(filter);
       System.out.println("Done C");
    }
    if(d==1)
    {
       collection.removeAll(filter);
       System.out.println("Done D");
    }

   System.out.println(filter);
   System.out.println(collection);



    FileWriter writer = null; 
    try {
        writer = new FileWriter(output);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Attribute_UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
   for(int i=0;i<collection.size();i++)
  {
      String str =collection.get(i).toString();
        try {
            writer.write(str);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Attribute_UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
  }
    try {
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Attribute_UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }``
```

}

The above code prints data and saves in new text file,but I am not able to delete data based on above conditions.

Comment: I suggest that you try to debug this code.

Comment: what values are being printed at  `System.out.println(filter);
   System.out.println(collection);`

Comment: Output of System.out.println(filter)=> [A, B, F] and System.out.println(collection)=>
[A -1 D -1 G -1 I -1 K -1 -2, A -1 D -1 G -1 J -1 K -1 -2, B -1 D -1 G -1 I -1 L -1 -2, C -1 E B -1 G -1 I -1 L -1 -2

Answer (score 0):

I think You should use Following way To delete Specific Data from Text File

1.you use Separator like pipe(|) to get distinct element from file
    e.g A -1|D -1|G -1|I -1|K -1 -2|A -1|D -1|G -1

2.then read file using buffredreader and append to the string using StringBuffer.

3.spilt this string using pipe
e.g String FileDataArray[]= sCurrentLine.split("\|");

4.check your condition like below

```
List list= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("fileDataArray"));
for(String data:fileDataArray)
{
if(!jCheckBox1.isSelected()&&data.contains("A"))
{ 
  list.removeAll(data);
 } 

      }`
```

5.and then write list in new file.
This is my suggestion.if you like pick it.``

Comment: Instead of using separator pipe(|) can I use '-1' as separator?

Comment: while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            FileDataArray= sCurrentLine.split("-1");
            collection.add(sCurrentLine);
           }                                         List list= new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("FileDataArray"));
   if(!jCheckBox1.isSelected())
   {
    for(String data:FileDataArray)
    {
       if(!jCheckBox1.isSelected()&&data.contains("A"))
       { 
       list.removeAll(data);
       } 
    }
   }  It is showing error at list.removeAll(data);

Comment: You can use -1 but its not split as you expect so when you use | then it split like[ A-1 A -1 D -1 G -1 I -1 K -1 -2 ]

Comment: and also use remove instead of removeall .its working on on my machine.